# Python function with Requests module working locally but not on AWS Lambda. NewConnectionError: Name or service not known

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests

I created the following Lambda function in Python 3.9 by creating a deployment package and importing the requests module using pip.
`pip install requests "urllib3<2" -t . --no-user`

```
import boto3
import json
import requests
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

token_endpoint='https://api.example.com/token'

def get_new_token(client_id, client_secret, token_endpoint):
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    data = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials', 'client_id': client_id, 'client_secret': client_secret}
    response = requests.post(token_endpoint, headers=headers, data=data, verify=False)
    print(response.text)
    if response.status_code !=200:
        print("ERROR=Failed to obtain token from the OAuth 2.0 server")
    else:
        body = json.loads(response.text)
        token = body['access_token']
        return token

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client_id, client_secret = get_secret(secret_name, region_name)
    token = get_new_token(client_id, client_secret, token_endpoint)
```

This script works locally but does not work on Lambda. I get the following error.

`[ERROR] ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.example.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /token (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xabcd>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known'))`

The Lambda function isn't connected to a VPC and has access to internet. I verified this by sending a get request to google.com which worked.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Maybe `api.example.com` is blocking AWS IPs. Its common practice to block connections from AWS IPs.